# Android - hide status and navigation bar completely for an app with nav drawer and app bar

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, android-statusbar, android-fullscreen, android-navigation-bar

How can I dynamically hide the status and the navigation bar **completely**?

The app contains a regular navigation drawer with a appbar / toolbar and FAB  buttons.

When switching to full screen, the **content** of the navigation and the status bar is scrolled away. Two empty bars are left on the screen. I want those empty bars to hide.

I created a [minimal demo app](https://github.com/johan974/android-fullscreen-with-drawerlayout.git). On the left is the regular app. When pushing on the fab, the app should be shown fullscreen.

[image]

How can I get the bars to hide?

QUESTION: Please write which change(s) are needed in the minimal demo project?

**Updated with a second solution**:

The GREAT solution provided by @Roaim works. Essential was to set the *android:fitsSystemWindows* layout property to false.

If you still have trouble with the showing and hiding of status/navigation bars, this solutin may help you.

Hide the bars completely:

```
public static void hideSystemUI() {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

And show all bars:

```
public static void showSystemUI() {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

The issue was with your layout file. I just set `android:fitsSystemWindows=false` to fix the issue. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/johan974/android-fullscreen-with-drawerlayout/pull/1) to your repo, which I think solves your issue.

[image]

---

You should follow the following official documentations:

- [Hide the status bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status)
- [Hide the navigation bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation)

---

> Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and Lower

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
        // the status bar.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    ...
}
```

> Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
```

> Hide the Navigation Bar

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
    // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
    // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
    // hide the navigation bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: G R E A T !!! Thank you very much! I awarded the Solved + Up + Bounty. Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

Go in values>styles

Now In App theme use

To make navigation bar transculate

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

To remove it make its color matched with your layout

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
```

OR Try this

```
public void FullScreencall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the edits and upate me It's working or not?

Comment: I have edited my answer please check and give me update It's working or not?

Comment: Thank you. 1) windowTranslucentNavigation does not remove it, but allows a different background color. 2) The navigationBarColor gives the letters another color, not the background. And the content below is not shown. 3) I tried your approach, and it works till Android 10 I guess. Answer 3 I already tried, see my question. Alas.

Comment: Great! now, we can say you have find your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<style name="MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
 ...
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
 ...
 </style>
```

Comment: but he wants to perform this action when click on button

Answer (score 1):

Try this to hide/show statusbar and navbar, both are parts of SystemUI.

```
fun setSystemUIVisibility(hide: Boolean) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val window = window.insetsController!!
        val windows = WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
        if (hide) window.hide(windows) else window.show(windows)
        // needed for hide, doesn't do anything in show
        window.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    } else {
        val view = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (hide) view else view.inv()
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Theme**

```
    <style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">shortEdges</item>
     </style>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
   <activity android:exported="false"
        android:name=".FullScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen"/>
```